# Envelope expiration date

Tags: docusignapi

Using the ListStatusChanges GetNotificationSettings api's I can get the SentDateTime and the ExpireAfter (ie. 120 days) from which I can calculate the expiration date of the envelope.  Is there an API which returns the actual expiration date of the envelope to avoid having to do this calculation?

If not is using the SentDateTime and the ExpireAfter the best method to get the expiration date?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [GetEnvelope](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/get-envelope-information/) method returns "expireDateTime"

Comment: Thanks bendowlingtech, GetEnvelope worked.